# How to pass an argument to a PowerShell script to match the column in csv file

Tags: powershell

```
$current_pc     = "$env:computername"
$filePath      = "c:\users\Ara\Desktop\parameters.csv"
$machineParams = Import-CSV $filePath
$info          = if($machineParams){$machineParams | where {$_.branch -eq $($current_pc.Substring($current_pc.length - 3,3))}}
             else{write-output "CSV not loaded"}
$info

Start-Process -FilePath "c:\users\Ara\Desktop\setup.msi"  -ArgumentList “/qf”, "DATABASE_ID=$($info.param1)" , "ODBC_DATABASE_NAME=$($info.ODBC_param2)" ,  "ODBC_ENGINE_NAME=$($info.param3)" -wait
```

CSV file looks like below

```
branch param1 param2  param3
------ ------ ------  ------
188    apr101 1.0.0.1 0
101    apr104 1.0.0.1 1
```

My question is what logic should I include in the script?
to run `install.ps1 -188` it takes values next to 188 in csv file

Comment: Thanks BenH, I am trying to edit, but Couldnt

Comment: Could you try to clarify your question? What exactly are you looking for? What's the expected outcome?

Comment: the script I posted match the computername and takes the values accordingly, but we do have some machines with diffrent naming cinvention. if script name is intasll.ps1. If I run install.ps1 -188, it should take the params next to 188

Answer (score 0):

I'd only read in parameters for the `$current_pc`

```
## Q:\Test\2018\05\29\SO_50590213.ps1
$current_pc     = "$env:computername"
$CurrBranch     = $current_pc.Substring($current_pc.length-3,3)
$filePath       = "c:\users\Ara\Desktop\parameters.csv"
$machineParams  = Import-CSV $filePath | where {$_.branch -eq $CurrBranch}
$info = if($machineParams){
    $machineParams
} else {
    write-output "no params for $CurrBranch"
}
$info

Start-Process -FilePath "c:\users\Ara\Desktop\setup.msi"  `
  -ArgumentList “/qf”, "DATABASE_ID=$($info.param1)", `
  "ODBC_DATABASE_NAME=$($info.ODBC_param2)", `
  "ODBC_ENGINE_NAME=$($info.param3)" -wait
```

Sample output (this pcs name ends with 610)

```
branch param1 param2  param3
------ ------ ------  ------
610    aprxxx 1.0.0.1 1
```

or  with no matching branch in file

```
no params for 610
```

Comment: Thanks lotPings, The scripts works good. what I am trying to do is to edit the script. I want to run from command window. If I open cmd and the powershell. Run command install.ps1 -188. Then the script looks for 188 under branch if it matches run that setup with parameters next to it

Comment: If my answer solves your question or is helpfule consider to  [check mark as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and/or [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)

Comment: Nope LotPings, it didnt solve. as I said My posted scripts woks good. but I want to pass parameter to script itself

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `param` block and define the default ID to be the computername substring.

```
param (
    $ID = (@($ENV:computername) | ForEach-Object {$_.Substring($_.length - 3,3)})
)
$filePath      = "c:\users\Ara\Desktop\parameters.csv"
$machineParams = Import-CSV $filePath | Where-Object {$_.branch -eq $ID}
$info          = if ($machineParams) {
                    $machineParams
                } else {
                    # Use a throw to error out when invalid csv 
                    throw "no params for $ID"
                }
$info

Start-Process -FilePath "c:\users\Ara\Desktop\setup.msi"  -ArgumentList “/qf”, "DATABASE_ID=$($info.param1)" , "ODBC_DATABASE_NAME=$($info.ODBC_param2)" ,  "ODBC_ENGINE_NAME=$($info.param3)" -wait
```

Then you can call your script and when you define the ID parameter, it will override the default scheme and when called without will use the computername scheme.

```
# Use computername scheme
install.ps1
# Use defined ID
install.ps1 -ID 188
```

Edit: Updated using @LotPings suggestions for filtering earlier

Comment: i ran the code and I am gettingThe term 'param' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify t
hat the path is correct and try again. "Missing ')' in function parameter list.
At line:1 char:36

An empty pipe element is not allowed.
At line:1 char:36"

Comment: @dj3094 Updated to wrap the entire parameter in parenthesis to fix that error message.

Comment: I saved the script as install.ps1 on my desktop.It works good. What if if I dont want to match that to computername. If I run the install.ps1 -ID 188, it goes through csv and take parameters,

Comment: @dj3094 If you just run `install.ps1` it will use the computer name substring, if you run `install.ps1 -ID 188` it will use `188` rather than the substring.

Comment: i changed it to $ID = ([INT32]$info.branch) i think its working, I will do some testing and get back to you, thanks